# Bat file to compare files within folder A against folder B

Tags: file, batch-file, command, compare, diff

Please can someone help with the below

I have two folders:

C:\FolderA
C:\FolderB

Folder A contains a bunch of files like an archive 
Folder B contains the same bunch of files with the same name, however some data within the files may be different.

I want to write a .bat file which uses the diff command to compare all the files from folder A to the files in folder B with the corresponding name (e.g. update0001 against update 0001) and outputs the difference in "C:\Folder C" with each file difference in a separate text output. (e.g one file is called “Error update0001” and another “Error Update0005”

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to check the files in two folders and give results.

```
fc /b "c:\folder a\*.*" "c:\folder b\*.*" >"c:\folder c\results.txt"
```